# python regular expression with utf8 issue

Tags: python, regex, utf-8, python-2.7

I got a file which includes many lines of plain utf-8 text. Such as below, by the by, it's Chinese.

```
PROCESS：类型：关爱积分[NOTIFY]   交易号：2012022900000109   订单号：W12022910079166    交易金额：0.01元    交易状态：true 2012-2-29 10:13:08
```

The file itself was saved in utf-8 format. file name is xx.txt

here is my python code, env is python2.7

```
#coding: utf-8
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'交易金额：(\d+)元')
for line in open('xx.txt'):
    match = pattern.match(line.decode('utf-8'))
    if match:
        print match.group()
```

The problematic thing here is I got no results.

I wanna get the decimal string from `交易金额：0.01元`, in here, which is `0.01`.

Why doesn't this code work? Can anyone explain it to me, I got no clue whatsoever.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. First you should use `re.compile(ur'<unicode string>')`. Also it is nice to add re.UNICODE flag (not sure if really needed here though). Next one is that still you will not receive a match since `\d+` doesn't handle decimals just a series of numbers, you should use `\d+\.?\d+` instead (you want number, probably a dot and a number). Example code:

```
#coding: utf-8

text = u"PROCESS：类型：关爱积分[NOTIFY]   交易号：2012022900000109   订单号：W12022910079166    交易金额：0.01元    交易状态：true 2012-2-29 10:13:08"
import re
pattern = re.compile(ur'交易金额：(\d+\.?\d+)元', re.UNICODE)

print pattern.search(text).group(1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [`.search()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) since [`.match()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) is like starting your regex with `^`, i.e. it only checks at the beginning of the string.

Comment: still not working. can u provide your code to accomplish this little task, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you use utf-8, you can use flags=re.LOCALE

```
#coding: utf-8
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'交易金额：(\d+\.?\d+)元', flags=re.LOCALE)
for line in open('xx.txt'):
    match = pattern.match(line)
```

More details, see [re.LOCALE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.LOCALE). There is no need to convert utf-8 to unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two small mistakes:

1. Using a `bytes` regex on a `unicode` string.
2. Missing decimal point in the regex.

When we fix the above mistakes, we get the following code.

```
#coding: utf-8
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'交易金额：([\.\d]+)元')
for line in open('xx.txt'):
    match = pattern.search(line)
    if match:
        print (match.groups())
```

In Python 2, it works because the regex and file are both byte strings. In Python 3, it works because both are unicode strings. This is a great example of how decoding the UTF-8 is unnecessary in 99% of programs (yet some languages insist on suggesting it).