# Extracting hashtags from paragraphs in unicode (for foreign languages) in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to work on a function to extract hashtags from paragraphs, basically words that starts with # (`#cool` `#life` `#cars` `#سيارات`)

I've tried several approaches such as using `split()` and using regular expressions, but got no where trying to include unicode characters for Arabic, Russian, etc..

I tried to use `split()` which works fine, but it will include any word and in my case, I cannot include words with special characters such as `,.%$]{}{)(..` also trying to include some validation such as word length not exceeding 15 characters.

I tried this approach -

```
def _strip_hash_tags(self, ):
    """tags should not be more than 15 characters"""
    hash_tags = re.compile(r'(?i)(?<=\#)\w+')
    return [i for i in hash_tags.findall(self.content) if len(i) < 15]
```

this works only for English and won't work for foreign languages. Any suggestion?

Comment: One of my favourite questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed here - [python regular expression with utf8 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546442/python-regular-expression-with-utf8-issue).

> First you should use `re.compile(ur'<unicode string>')`. Also it is nice
>   to add `re.UNICODE` flag (not sure if really needed here though).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import re


def strip_hash_tags(content):
    """tags should not be more than 15 characters"""
    hash_tags = re.compile(ur'(?i)(?<=\#)\w+',re.UNICODE)
    return [i for i in hash_tags.findall(content) if len(i) < 15]

str = u"am trying to work on a function to extract hashtags from paragraphs, basically words that starts with # (#cool #life #cars #سيارات)"

print(strip_hash_tags(str))

# [u'cool', u'life', u'cars', u'\xd8\xb3\xd9']
```

Comment: GLES thanks for the answer.. It helped me a lot.. but, there is one scenario which is not covering.. when using hash tags such as #sweet-potatoes for example, it will extract #sweet as a hashtag.. which is incorrect in my case. it should ignore the whole hashtag as long as its containing special characters. Any idea how can tackle this?

Comment: You're matching words using - `\w+`, modify it to include the dashes, *maybe* like this - `\w+-\w+`. I've forgotten regex :)