# Python Regex UTF-8 Syntax error

Tags: python, regex, utf-8

I've been trying to cleanup some text. But got stuck on regex, finally got around with re.sub. But end up with syntax error.
Original Code:

## Test for name cleanup

```
import re

input = u'CHEZ MADU 東久留米店（シェマディ）【東京都東久留米市】'

pattern = re.compile(ur'(【(.*?)\】)', re.UNICODE)\

print(re.sub(input, pattern, ''))
```

Gave me this error:

```
  File "retest01.py", line 6
    pattern = re.compile(ur'(【(.*?)\】)', re.UNICODE)\
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've been testing code from another regex thread: [python regular expression with utf8 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546442/python-regular-expression-with-utf8-issue)

It gave same error. What could be possible the source of problem here?

Comment: what version of python are you using? If you are using version 3 try removing the `u` prefix on the strings since all strings are unicode.

Comment: python 3, following the answer `pattern = re.compile(u'(【(.*?)\】)')` is working for me

Comment: In Python 3, you do not need `u` prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the raw string notation, it works out fine for me. Additionally, I don't think you're using the `re.sub` properly:

`re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

This didn't throw an error for me:

```
import re
input = u'CHEZ MADU 東久留米店（シェマディ）【東京都東久留米市】'
pattern = re.compile(u'(【(.*?)\】)', re.UNICODE)
print(re.sub(pattern, '', input))
```

This works on python 2 and 3, but you don't need the unicode specifier on 3.

Comment: thank you. looks like my beginner problem. will be more careful

Answer (score 0):

The `ur'....'` syntax is invalid since Python 3.3 (see http://bugs.python.org/issue15096 )

The syntax error is, a bit surprisingly, indicated at the end of the string...

```
>>> ru'my string'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ru'my string'
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, in Python 3, you can use either:

- `'my string'` or `u'mystring'`, which mean the same (the latter was reintroduced in Python 3.3 for compatibility with Python 2 code, see [PEP 414](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/) )
- or `r'my string with \backslashes'` for a "raw" string.